# "Composite" algebraic data types in Scala and Haskell

Tags: scala, haskell, algebraic-data-types

While trying to describe a portion of Sql with Algebraic Data Types in Scala I met a neccessity to create subtraits of the root trait which represents the data type. Since meeting this requirement produced a code that I'm not sure is possible to represent with Haskell's ADTs, and since, in difference to Haskell, ADT is not a native construct to Scala, I am now wondering:

1. Am I right that it is impossible to represent a model such as a type `Sql` having a "subtype" `Statement` having a constructor `Select` in Haskell? *(It seems like [this](http://www.nt.ntnu.no/users/haugwarb/Programming/OHaskell/o_haskell_tutorial.html#sect4) may be related).*
2. If so, is the term "ADT" applicable to the code that I produced?
3. If it is, does this make Scala actually more powerful than Haskell in that aspect?
4. If it doesn't, what are the reasons for this functionality not to be implemented in Haskell? It makes me think that I might be overcomplicating things in my model

Here's the model I'm talking about:

```
sealed trait Sql


sealed trait Statement 
  extends Sql

sealed case class Union 
  ( left : Statement, 
    right : Statement ) 
  extends Statement

sealed case class Select
  ( /** other fields don't matter **/
    where : Where )
  extends Statement


sealed trait Where 
  extends Sql

sealed case class And
  ( left : Where,
    right : Where )
  extends Where

sealed case class Or
  ( left : Where,
    right : Where )
  extends Where

sealed case class Equals
  ( /** fields don't matter **/ )
  extends Where
```

Comment: Note to readers not familiar with the terminology: *ADT* in this question refers exclusively to Algebraic Data Types, and *not* to Abstract Data Types.

Comment: @JörgWMittag: It's mentioned in the first sentence

Comment: Yes, I know. But the vast majority of programmers has probably never even heard of Algebraic Data Types, so they might not be accustomed to the abbreviation *ADT* being used for it instead of for Abstract Data Types.

Comment: I don't speak Scala, but I looked that up on wikipedia: aren't "traits" more like typeclasses (interfaces), rather than types? (Since you're speaking of a "SQL type"). In that case, ADTs are something totally different.

Comment: @phg Traits in Scala are used for all: Interfaces, mimicking Type Classes functionality with a pattern and mimicking ADTs with a pattern, as in this case. In the ADT pattern a trait represents the Haskell's data type and case classes extending this trait represent the Haskell's type constructors. In this sense `data Maybe a = None | Just a` can be mimicked as `sealed trait Maybe[A]; case object None extends Maybe[A]; case class Just[A](a : A) extends Maybe[A]`

Comment: Ok, that quite makes sense if I look at the structure again.

Comment: given that case classes can't be extended, what's the value of marking them `sealed`?

Comment: @ErikAllik They can be extended by standard classes. E.g., `case class A (a: Int); class B (b: Int) extends A(2)`

Answer (score 10, accepted):

**1.** No, since your root trait is sealed, it **is** possible to represent the presented hierarchy as ADTs:

```hs
data Sql = Statement Statement | Where Where
        --           ^ This is the *type* called `Statement`
        -- ^ This is the *constructor* called `Statement`

data Statement = Union Statement Statement | Select Where

data Where = And Where Where | Or Where Where | Equals
```

It is possible in this case, because you are able to enumerate all of the "subclasses" of your data type (`Sql` in this case), which makes it possible to convert them into ADT constructors. It is only difficult to emulate type hierarchies as ADTs if you want to allow "constructors"/"sub-classes" to be added arbitrarily by the user.

**2.** The term ADT is never applicable to Scala code since Scala lacks ADTs in the language. However, the classes that you've presented behave similarly to ADTs, so I'd say "close enough."

**3 & 4.** The languages have different strengths and weaknesses.

Haskell can emulate every Scala language feature, and Scala can emulate every Haskell feature, since both languages are turing complete, and allow for different levels of meta-programming. Haskell does of course have Template Haskell, which allows for anything to be emulated -- you could probably use TH to be able to write Scala code in a Haskell file and have it be compiled as Haskell.

Objects and inheritance are not needed in Haskell, and ADTs are mostly not needed in Scala, so there's no reason to compare the two. Most object-oriented features can also be emulated with simple Haskell type classes and data types, and using module boundaries. ADTs can be emulated in Scala with case classes, and Haskell type classes can be emulated with implicit parameters and implicit object instances.

However, I'd say that it in general is easier to emulate certain Scala features in Haskell, though, because Haskell allows for more "implicit language extensions" than Scala does. What I mean by that is that if you want to emulate Haskell `Monad`s in Scala, you have to write lots of code in the parts that use the `Monad`s, while if you want to emulate, let's say, Scala's delimited continuations or implicit parameters in Haskell, you can simply write a `Monad` instance (for continuations) or a multi-param type class (for implicit parameters) once for that, and the code that you later write in your actual functions will look very close to the Scala code without much boiler plate. Many if not most of Scala's advanced features do also originate from either Haskell or OCaml, so they are already there and don't need to be translated.

In other words: The complex code required to add the new feature only has to be added in one location in Haskell, after which it can be used in multiple locations very easily, while you often have to add lots of "noise" everywhere in your Scala code if you want to emulate a Haskell feature.

Comment: Oh! So, `Select Where Equals` to get an `Equals` value of `Sql` type, right? My mind was too targeted at inheritance to get it ) Thanks! A very good answer!

Comment: @Nikita, just `Where Equals`.

Comment: It looks like your model doesn't exactly match because its translation back to Scala will be different. Here's how the relation of `Statement` type to `Sql` type of your model would be translated to Scala: `sealed trait Sql; case class StatementSql(s: Statement); sealed trait Statement`. I'm leaning towards the conclusion that the model presented in my question really has no direct counterpart in Haskell and as such does not quite fulfill the ADT pattern of Scala.

Comment: No, it matches the Scala version, because they have the same semantics. It's like saying there's a difference between "1 + 2" and "3". Yes, you can *see* that there's a difference, but they are semantically identical and isomorphic. And even if what you say is correct, it means that the Scala version does not "fulfull the ADT pattern in Haskell," because there is no such thing as ADTs in Scala :)

Comment: There's no ADT construct in Scala but there is a pattern. What I'm saying is that although my model can be viewed as an ADT, as I think we've established, it probably doesn't quite follow the pattern. Please prepend my name if you answer, or I won't get notified.

Comment: @NikitaVolkov, yes, you are of course correct, but the statement "the model ... does not quite fulfill the ADT pattern of Scala" still makes no sense to me. It does 100% represent a valid ADT emulation with a 1:1 mapping to the Haskell version, even though it's not an ADT itself.

Answer (score 5):

You can imitate the Scala design in Haskell, although Haskell encourages using qualified types and sum types instead of Scala's inheritance and subtyping.  Going off my limited knowledge of Scala, I wrote the same stuff in Haskell below.

- Traits are classes
- Case classes are ADTs
- Trait inheritance is class membership
- Trait-typed members are bounded existential types
- Class `Typeable` is used for downcasting

```hs
-- Define traits
class Typeable a => Sql a
class (Typeable a, Sql a) => Statement a
class (Typeable a, Sql a) => Where a

-- Define case classes
data Union  where Union     :: (Statement a, Statement b) => a -> b -> Union deriving (Typeable)
data Select where Select    :: Where a => a -> Select                        deriving (Typeable)          

data And    where And       :: (Where a, Where b) => a -> b -> And           deriving (Typeable)
data Or     where Or        :: (Where a, Where b) => a -> b -> Or            deriving (Typeable)
data Equals where Equals    :: Equals                                        deriving (Typeable)

-- Define subtyping
instance Sql Union
instance Statement Union
instance Sql Select
instance Statement Select
instance Sql And
instance Where And
instance Sql Or
instance Where Or
instance Sql Equals
instance Where Equals
```

In Haskell, you would probably use sum types instead of the `Statement` and `Where` classes.

```hs
class Sql a
instance Sql Statement
instance Sql Where

data Statement = Union Statement Statement | Select Where
data Where = And Where Where | Or Where Where | Equals
```

Comment: To clarify: This is a translation of Haskell ADTs into Scala and the Scala representation back into Haskell. It should make anyone's brain hurt, but it works, of course!

Comment: Note that this version allows additional traits to be added to a class after the class has been defined. I don't mean in the `new And(...) with Statement` sense, I mean that you can add a trait such that *every* instance of `And` has that trait afterwards. That is not possible with Scala traits, afaik.

Answer (score 0):

One possible answer to question 4:

Haskell's type inference (Hindley-Milner) would have problems in the presence of inheritance, so Scala has inheritance but a less powerfull type inferencer.